# LEGO® is broken in the SE Site Directory

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, html-entities

The ® is not being displayed properly in the StackExchange [Site Directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites) (listed newest first).

[image: Lego Bricks]

---

Seen under Mac 10.6.8

- Google Chrome 15.0.874.121
- Safari Version 5.0.5 (6533.21.1)

---

A similar problem occurs in the Accounts tab of the [user page]
[3](https://stackexchange.com/users/372965?tab=accounts). It occurs on both Chromium and Firefox, both at the latest versions.

[image]

It looks like SE should simply use Unicode instead of HTML-entities, which then get wrongly escaped somewhere.

Comment: A [similar bug](http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17/problem-with-r-mark-encoding) was reported (and resolved) at the start of private beta.

Comment: This also appears in the site list in the multicollider, and on the account tabs on SO and MSO.

Comment: If I'm reading it right, that is *triple* encoded! "Triple the safety!" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, somehow this snuck back in.  It should be fixed now.