# Ampersand (&) entity displayed as clear text on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, html-entities

An "&" is displayed as its HTML entity `&amp;` on a [commitment page on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6388/chinese-language-usage?commit=1):

[image: screenshot of buggy page]

Comment: &#87;&#104;&#111;&#111;&#112;&#115;

Comment: heh; but... at least double-encoding is better than zero-encoding ;p

Comment: If you used Hungarian this would never happen!

Comment: I thought this was already reported, but I could not find a question about the same topic.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It's similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113026/lego-is-broken-in-the-se-site-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woops, another double-encoding bug introduced when I converted the view to Razor.

It's fixed now – thanks a lot.